# Uncompressing first N bytes and last N bytes from large gzip archive located on s3 without downloading and uncompressing whole file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, compression, gzip

I have a genuine use case to traverse s3 bucket using Python and extract header and footer from large (40GB) gzip archives without uncompressing whole file.

The code which actually works as expected but only for header:

```
def get_first_line_from_s3(bucket_name, file_name):
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    chunk_size = 1024
    
    range_header = f"bytes=0-{chunk_size}"
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name, Range=range_header)
    
    content = response['Body'].read()
    
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 32)
    
    first_line_decompressed = decompressor.decompress(content)
    
    return first_line_decompressed.decode().split('\n')[0]
```

But slight modification to read trailer throw an error

Code for footer

```
def get_last_line_from_s3(bucket_name, file_name):
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    chunk_size = 1024
    
    response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    file_size = response['ContentLength']
    
    range_header=f'bytes={file_size - 1024}-{file_size}'
    response_for_last_bytes = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name, Range=range_header)
    last_n_bytes = response_for_last_bytes['Body'].read()
    
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS | 32)
    
    last_line_decompressed = decompressor.decompress(last_n_bytes)
    
    print (last_line_decompressed)
```

zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

But I tried gzip.open() and code actually works for both header and footer but locally:

```
def get_first_and_last_line(path):
   with open(path) as f:
      with gzip.open(f) as f_gzip:
         header_chunk = 1024
         f_gzip.seek(0, 0)
         header_raw = f_gzip.read(header_chunk).decode()
         print(header_raw)

         footer_chunk = 128
         f_gzip.seek(-footer_chunk, 2)
         footer_raw = f_gzip.read(footer_chunk).decode()
         print(footer_raw)
```

Also works on s3 (after replacing open with s3fs.S3Filesystem().open) but with a small caveat it uncompressing the  whole file which defeat my primary objective:

```
def get_last_line_from_s3(s3_path):
   fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
      with fs.open(s3_path) as f:
         with gzip.open(f) as f_gzip:
            header_chunk = 1024
            f_gzip.seek(0, 0)
            header_raw = f_gzip.read(header_chunk).decode()
            print(header_raw)

            footer_chunk = 128
            f_gzip.seek(-footer_chunk, 2)
            footer_raw = f_gzip.read(footer_chunk).decode()
            print(footer_raw)
```

I need to uncompres first N bytes and last N bytes from file on s3 without downloading or uncompressing the whole file.

Comment: In gzip, the CRC and the *history* used for compression depend on all previous bytes in the files. What you want is similar to recovering a damaged file. This is outlined here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180708075208/http://www.gzip.org/recover.txt I don't think this is reasonable for your use-case. A block-compressed format like bzip2 might work better for you

Comment: Thanks for reply, My use case is slightly different. I have loaded 30 years of history. Files are huge ~40GB. I need to skim quickly on files to get the metadata from header and footer.

Comment: But I like your view on a problem. It is possible  to uncompress damaged archive using python? I tried to read first 1024 bytes and last 1024 bytes, concatenate them and decompress using code in my post but without success.
---
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back

Answer (score 2):

Your "code actually works for both header and footer but locally" is also decompressing the entire gzip file in order to print the footer. There is no way to avoid that. At least not without previously having decompressed the entire gzip file and saving an entry point near the end, or without compressing the data in a special way to create entry points.

A normally constructed gzip file can only be accessed at the end by reading the entire thing.

There is generally no need to download and *save* the whole thing. A gzip file can be decompressed as a stream. You can just read it a chunk at a time and decompress as you go. That's what the gzip module is doing internally in your "Also works on s3" code.